# Leaflet in shiny efficient way to combine data with shape file

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

To implement a map tool into my app I loaded from GADM a `.rds` shape file.

Displaying the map in shiny works fine, but I am not sure about the next step. As far as I understood it I have to match the `.rds` file with my actual data?
They both share a common ID but a simple `merge()` results in `NA` inside the data fields. What is an efficient way to bring the shape file and my data (inside an reactive expression) together?

EDIT:
My code so far:

```
dat <- reactive({
    adm <- getData('GADM', country='DEU', level=1)
   #test data
    test_data <- data.frame(ID_1= (1:16), N= (1:16))
   #join
    joined <- merge(Map_ger, test_data, by.x="ID_1")
   #color pallete
    pal <- colorNumeric(
     palette = "Blues",
     domain = joined$N
)

  })

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldGrayCanvas") %>%  
  addPolygons(data=dat(),stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, fillOpacity = 1,
              color = ~pal(N))        
  })
```

Problem now is how to access the pal values from my reactive expression: `dat()$pal` is not working.

Comment: Two things: First, I don't see where your `Map_ger` object comes from. Second, if you use `sp::merge(adm, test_data, by.x="ID_1")` you should get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have the answer already:

> They both share a common ID but a simple `merge()` results in `NA` inside
>   the data fields.

If you are getting `NA` values your `merge` command does not work. Without looking at the data, you may consider attempting to verify that values in your vectors are actually the same, for example:

```
a <- 1:10
b <- rep(1:15, 3)
unique(b) %in% unique(a)
```

You may want for the expression:

```
all(unique(b) %in% unique(a))
```

to return `TRUE`. Common approaches concerned with fixing the problem may involve running:

```
trimws(tolower(as.character(yourID)))
```

On both of your `ID` columns to ensure that blank spaces or variable use of lower/upper case create problems when merging; this is a common hindrance when handling data with geographic names.

---

*Please note that the described `merge` problem would be much easier to solve if you would consider posting some sample data.*